# File can be opened but not read QNX

Tags: c, testing, readfile, qnx

I need to test the following situation: a program in C, that runs on QNX-system, can open a file but can not read it. My task is to make sure that in this situation the program delivers the correct error message.
Manipulating file permissions does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to simulate this situation? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you have to lock a file by another process that runs in background. 
Example in Perl (file_lock.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);
my $fh = '/file/that/needs/to/be/locked';
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock mailbox - $!\n";
seek($fh, 0, SEEK_END) or die "Cannot seek - $!\n";
while (true) {}
```

Run that script in background, it will lock the file you need:

```
root@server:~# perl file_lock.pl &
```

Then run your C code and test if the error handling works correctly.